# Joomla get translation - custom

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a custom component generating a email newsletter. Now I want to generate the html in the language of the user.

But how can I access the user language file within the code?

using

```
$lang->setLanguage( $language );
$lang->load();
```

does not wrok

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the email is generated in front-end while user is navigating your site, you can get the language user is using:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$langTag = $lang->getTag();
echo $langTag; // for example, "en-GB" for English.
```

$langTag could be different if your site is a multilingual site and user is browsing in a different language, not English.

When you get the language tag, you can generate your newsletter in that language and send.

If you send newsletter from back-end, you can get user's language like this

```
$user = JFactory::getUser(USER ID HERE); // $user = JFactory::getUser(123);
$langTag $user->getParam('language', 'en-GB'));
echo $langTag;
```

User can change his/her language in user profile, if user uses the default language, $langTag will be empty, so we use 'en-GB' as fallback.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

include

```
protected $autoloadLanguage = true;
```

inside your component class in php. And use language files.

Comment: hmm no solution in Joomla?

Comment: What do you mean? It's built-in Joomla engine for multilanguage support. First- you make language files, include them in your component, then you use this code to enable language according to user language.